# The transient instantaneous power dissipation of an impedance

Tags: power, impedance, transient

Suppose we have a resistor of value R in parallel with an inductor of value L with series resistance R. The impedance of the network is $$Z= R\frac{sL+R}{sL+2R}.$$

[image: schematic]

The
Voltage \$V_0(t)\$ across the impedance can be found by the inverse Laplace transform of \$Z(s)I_0(s)\$.

The total power going into the impedance is $$ P_{total}(t)=V_0(t)I_0(t).$$
The current through the R branch is $$I_{R}(t)=\frac{V_0(t)}{R} $$ and the RL branch current is $$ I_L(t)=I_0(t)-I_R(t). $$

From analysis of the circuit, we know that at any point in time, the instantaneous resistive power dissipation is
$$P_R(t)=I_R(t)^2R+I_L(t)^2R.$$

We also know that the instantaneous power energizing the inductor is

$$P_L(t)=\frac{1}{2}L\frac{dI_L(t)^2}{dt}$$
such that

$$P_{total}(t)=P_L(t)+P_R(t)$$

is always true.

We can define equivalents voltages such that

$$V_{R_{eq}}(t)=\frac{P_R(t)}{I_0(t)}$$

and

$$V_{L_{eq}}(t)=\frac{P_L(t)}{I_0(t)}$$

such that

$$V_0(t)=V_{L_{eq}}(t)+V_{R_{eq}}(t).$$

These equivalent voltages can easily be calculated in the time domain using the above equations for any arbitrary \$I_0(t)\$.

The transfer function Z(s) gives a relationship between \$I_0(t)\$ and the \$V_0(t)\$. The question is: is there such a closed form transfer function that directly relates \$V_{R_{eq}}(t)\$ and \$V_{L_{eq}}(t)\$ with any \$I_0(t)\$? Also, is it possible to determine the the instantaneous transient power dissipation of an arbitrary transfer function subject to an arbitrary input current without knowing what the circuit looks like?

Comment: You mean the ones that you gave at the end? As for your second question, that's v(t)*i(t), where v(t) is the voltage across the black box and i(t) is the current through it. Unless I misunderstood.

Comment: The equations at the end are not transfer functions in the s-domain. For the second question I am making the distinction between total power into the black box which is v(t)*i(t) versus the actual resistive power dissipation. This is analogous to finding real power versus the apparent power in harmonic analysis since there is also reactive power present.

Comment: Your question is about: "*a closed form transfer function that directly relates VReq(t) and VLeq(t) with any I0(t)*" -- not I0(**s**), hence my reply above. In your second question, since you are dealing with an *arbitrary* transfer function, then there's no way to know what's inside, which means you won't even know whether there are resistive elements. That's like asking if you can predict the future accurately. I can almost [hear the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdhAfMor9BM). ;-)